# How to construct this NHibernate query

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have a one-to-many relationship. I would like to construct this query:

Give me all the parents that have only one child and for this child `child.Type=X`

Since I 'm learning, please show me the query with the Criteria API and with HQL.

And btw, is there any automatic way to know what HQL is identical to a criteria expression ?

**Update:**

It seems I found how to do it in HQL:

```
@"select Parent
    from Parent parent
        join parent.Children ch
        where (ch.Type = :chType) and
              (select count(*) from parent.Children) = 1")
```

But is it well done? How is the performance? I have the intuition that the count(*) is not well placed...

Comment: I think you will get a better response if you post your mapping file, code class, and some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @David Pellerin about the ambiguity of the question.  However, I was literally *just* putting together a Lunch'n'Learn about this very topic, so using the typical Customer, Orders relationship . . .

Criteria API:

```
public IList<Customer> GetCustomersWithOrdersAfterDate(DateTime sinceDate)
{
   return Session.ICriteria.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer))
      .CreateCriteria("Orders")
      .Add(Expression.Gt("OrderDate", sinceDate))
      .List<Customer>();
}
```

HQL (which looks a ton like SQL, only you don't have to know the entire relationship graph):

```
public IList<Customer> GetCustomersWithOrdersAfterDate(DateTime sinceDate)
{
    Session.CreateQuery("select c from Customer c, c.Orders.elements o WHERE o.OrderDate > :orderDate).SetDateTime("orderDate", sinceDate).List<Customer>();
}
```

BTW:
if you are just learning, stop everything you are doing and go watch [these screencasts](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com).  Probably the best set of videos I've seen regarding nHibernate.  Highly, highly recommended.

Another useful link to address your "having count = 1" requirement is [here](http://www.nablasoft.com/alkampfer/index.php/2008/02/27/nhibernate-icriteria-count-and-the-missing-of-having-clause/).  Fairly complicated, but I've adapted something similar with some success.

Comment: Thanks. My question was theoretical, that's why I have no example. I know the basic of the criteria api as you are showing it, but you don't tell me the main thing I was requesting: in your example, I want to get the customers who have only one order.